# No secrets were provided

Tags: networking, kubuntu

I am faced with a now router (using Kubuntu 22.04) and get the message:
Wireless Interface (wlo1)
"*No secrets were provided* "
And its asking repetitive for the password, which is definitely correct since windows is connecting with it immediately.

Some users (searched online) say its the KDE wallet, but I doubt it, as it would connect at least one time then, and a Lubuntu 22.04 live stick also doesn’t connect.
Any solution known?

---

here is is journalctl

```
   rolfarius@rolfarius-VivoBook-ASUSLaptop-X513EA-K513EA:~$ journalctl -f
Jun 17 16:58:54 rolfarius-VivoBook-ASUSLaptop-X513EA-K513EA systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jun 17 16:58:54 rolfarius-VivoBook-ASUSLaptop-X513EA-K513EA kernel: wlo1: associate with cc:32:e5:d6:6c:21 (try 2/3)
Jun 17 16:58:54 rolfarius-VivoBook-ASUSLaptop-X513EA-K513EA kernel: wlo1: associate with cc:32:e5:d6:6c:21 (try 3/3)
Jun 17 16:58:55 rolfarius-VivoBook-ASUSLaptop-X513EA-K513EA kernel: wlo1: association with cc:32:e5:d6:6c:21 timed out
Jun 17 16:58:55 rolfarius-VivoBook-ASUSLaptop-X513EA-K513EA duckpowered.actual-service[8901]: 1845000
Jun 17 16:58:55 rolfarius-VivoBook-ASUSLaptop-X513EA-K513EA wpa_supplicant[1005]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="TP-Link_6C21" auth_failures=1 duration=10 reason=CONN_FAILED
Jun 17 16:58:55 rolfarius-VivoBook-ASUSLaptop-X513EA-K513EA NetworkManager[942]: <info>  [1687010335.0484] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: associating -> disconnected
Jun 17 16:58:55 rolfarius-VivoBook-ASUSLaptop-X513EA-K513EA NetworkManager[942]: <info>  [1687010335.0484] device (p2p-dev-wlo1): supplicant management interface state: associating -> disconnected
Jun 17 16:58:56 rolfarius-VivoBook-ASUSLaptop-X513EA-K513EA duckpowered.actual-service[8926]: 697000
```

TP-Link_6C21 is the wlan, in the 6th line

it doesnt have Soft blocked:

```
0: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
1: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
```

The output of this code

```
echo -e "network={\nssid="TP-Link_6C21"\npsk="Your wlan password"\n}" > ~/wlan.conf
```

was

```
»Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant Line 2: failed to parse ssid 'TP-Link_6C21'. Line 2: failed to parse ssid 'TP-Link_6C21'. Line 3: Invalid PSK '60269454'. Line 3: failed to parse psk '60269454'. Line 4: failed to parse network block. Failed to read or parse configuration '/home/rolfarius/wlan.conf'. : CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all«
```

Comment: May you can share the output from `journalctl -f` while you trying to connecting to your wlan?

Comment: could you check if your kernel has a soft block for your wlan? with `sudo rfkill list`

Comment: Have you tried connecting via the command line? `nmcli d wifi connect [SSID] password [Your password]` ?

Comment: I just did ... and the Wi-Fi password dialog pops up asking for the password :) I am now with the phone hotspot

Comment: Could you tried it with wpa_supplicant via command line: `echo -e "network={\nssid="TP-Link_6C21"\npsk="Your wlan password"\n}" > ~/wlan.conf `  and then `wpa_supplicant -i wlo1 -c ~/wlan.conf`

Comment: Its the same problem. Before your post I found `nmcli con modify TP-Link_6C21 802-1x.private-key-password-flags 4`  `nmcli con show TP-Link_6C21 | grep "802-1x.private-key-password-flags` but after first line »Error: Failed to modify connection 'TP-Link_6C21': 802-1x.eap: property is missing« Still the same problem.

Comment: The output of your code was »Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
Line 2: failed to parse ssid 'TP-Link_6C21'.
Line 2: failed to parse ssid 'TP-Link_6C21'.
Line 3: Invalid PSK '60269454'.
Line 3: failed to parse psk '60269454'.
Line 4: failed to parse network block.
Failed to read or parse configuration '/home/rolfarius/wlan.conf'.
: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all«

Comment: Please edit those results into your question.

Comment: The problem is solved, but without any changes to the system. 
The router has two SSIDs, only one was activated (it belongs to the landlord).

(The second has by default the appendix _5G )

After enabling it and change the password Kubuntu accepted it, also other live systems (debian, ubuntu).

Comment: You can answer your own question and select it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved, but without any changes to the system.
The router has two SSIDs, only one was activated.

(The second has by default the appendix _5G ) After enabling it and changing the password Kubuntu accepted it, also other live systems (debian, ubuntu, which did not before).

Comment: Does `iwlist scan` show both SSIDs?

Comment: No 
"lo        Interface doesn't support scanning ..... Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"TP-Link_6C21_5G" 
Tehn the Bit Rates, and some IE unknown: numbers

Comment: I dont know any of the here suggested commands, and maybe some of the ones from lucki1000 have had an impact... no idea, but being glad its working finaly

Comment: @Raffles

_Does iwlist scan show both SSIDs?_ What does it say to you?

Comment: It should show all SSIDs that are being transmitted. Here is the [man page](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/cs/man8/iwlist.8.html) for `iwlist`.